# Avoid repeatable code with Observables(DRY)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, dry

Here is my code (with renamed methods) from Angular:

I have a function interface/contract

```
type IAutocomlete = (
  term: string,
  selectedIds?: string[]
) => Observable<TableFilterQueryResponse[]>;
```

This is my draft service that I want to inject in my Components in the future. I will have more methods with similar implementation.

```
    export class SuperCleanService {
      constructor(
        private dataController: DataController,
        private serviceController: ServiceController
      ) {}
    .....
    private searchAs$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.dataController
          .service1GET(term, selectedIds)
          .pipe(
            map((res) =>
              res.map((a) => ({
                viewValue: a.name,
                value: a.id
              }))
            )
          );
      };
      private searchB$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.serviceController
          .service1(term, selectedIds)
          .pipe(
            map((res) =>
              res.map((a) => ({
                viewValue: a.id,
                value: a.id
              }))
            )
          );
      };
      private searchC$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.dataController
          .service2GET(term, selectedIds)
          .pipe(
            map((res) =>
              res.map((a) => ({
                viewValue: a.name,
                value: a.id
              }))
            )
          );
      };
    ...
    }
```

How can I refactor (following DRY rule) and make it as clean as possible? My main goal is to avoid using map in each function.

Comment: What would be the logic to determine which method out of the three should be called?

Comment: Actually there may be more than three. I will have callback function with switch case inside that will call some of these functions depending on parameter I give. The whole idea is to call one general query from every component I inject this service.

Answer (score 2):

### Custom Operator

Consider creating a custom operator that houses the reusable logic.

**custom-pipe.ts**

```js
import { pipe, of } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

export function myCustomOperator() {
  return pipe(
    map((res) =>
      res.map((a) => ({
        viewValue: a.name,
        value: a.id
      }))
    )
  );
}
```

Your component will become:

```js
export class SuperCleanService {
  constructor(
    private dataController: DataController,
    private serviceController: ServiceController
  ) {}
.....
  private searchAs$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
    return this.dataController
      .service1GET(term, selectedIds)
      .pipe(
        myCustomOperator()
      );
  };
  private searchB$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
    return this.serviceController
      .service1(term, selectedIds)
      .pipe(
        myCustomOperator()
      );
  };
  private searchC$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
    return this.dataController
      .service2GET(term, selectedIds)
      .pipe(
        myCustomOperator()
      );
  };
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use generics with wrapper method which accepts autocomplete function and maps to desired result.

```
interface Autocomplete {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
}

type IAutocomplete = (
  term: string,
  selectedIds?: string[]
) => Observable<TableFilterQueryResponse[]>;

type AutocompleteCallback<T> = (
  term: string,
  selectedIds?: string[]
) => Observable<T[]>;

...

  // use instance arrow function to preserve 'this' in callback method
  private autocompleteMapper = <T extends Autocomplete>(
    callback: AutocompleteCallback<T>,
    term: string,
    selectedIds: string[]
  ) => {
    return callback(term, selectedIds).pipe(
      map((res) =>
        res.map((a) => ({
          viewValue: a.name,
          value: a.id
        }))
      )
    );
  };

  private search1$: IAutocomplete = (term, selectedIds) => {
    return this.autocompleteMapper<ResponseInterface>(
      this.dataControllerService.service1GET,
      term,
      selectedIds
    );
  };

  ...

``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class SuperCleanService {
    constructor(
    private dataController: DataController,
    private serviceController: ServiceController
    ) {}

    private performSeach: = (caller, resultMapper) => {
        return caller()
        .pipe(
            map((res) =>
                res.map(resultMapper)
            )
        );
    }

    private searchAs$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.performSeach(
            () => this.serviceController.service1GET(term, selectedIds),
            (a) => ({
                viewValue: a.name,
                value: a.id
            })
        )
    };

    private searchB$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.performSeach(
            () => this.serviceController.service1(term, selectedIds),
            (a) => ({
                viewValue: a.id,
                value: a.id
            })
        )
    };

    private searchC$: IAutocomlete = (term, selectedIds) => {
        return this.performSeach(
            () => this.serviceController.service2GET(term, selectedIds)
            (a) => ({
                viewValue: a.name,
                value: a.id
            })
        )
    };
}
```

I'd do something like this to start with - sorry I've not added the proper Typescript annotations but i think you get the idea. 
The `caller` and `mapper` args are two callbacks.

This way you don't repeat the logic to call pipe and map, you are free to use different params and mapping functions. Also, your methods are still explicit, they can take arbitrary params and can do extra logic before calling the internal search method, without too much magic.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is, is there any service or component in your app that does NOT need to map the data? If all consumers need the data mapped as you showed, then why not have the `DataController` and `ServiceController` perform the mapping there?

If there are consumers that don't need the data map, then one thing you can do to achieve more DRY code is to set the repeated code as its own expression in one place, and then reuse it.

---

example

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const mapView = map((data: any) => ({ viewValue: data.name, value: data.id }));

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DryService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  method1() {
    return this.http.get<any>('').pipe(mapView);
  }

  method2() {
    return this.http.get<any>('').pipe(mapView);
  }
}
```